# Importing external library into Xcode project

Tags: objective-c

For some reason, when I try importing a library into my xcode project, it's not recognizing it. It says:

Libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

ect, ect

Why am I getting this? I'm imported these and I see them in my "linked frameworks" folder. I actually just imported another applications frameworks/libaries and code so I can add it to my app...it compiles in the other app that I copied from, but when I import into mine, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the 'Header Search Paths' in your xcode project's settings. For libxml2, the path is this: `${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/**`

Comment: weird. Now it says "cocoa/cocoa.h: no such file or directory"

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know about that. I assume you have linked the Cocoa Framework to your project, correct?

Comment: yep! - I read somewhere that the error means that I didn't implement the header correctly...any ideas?

Comment: oh btw...this is for a mac app.

Comment: Odd, does the error persist if you change the path to the 'User Header Search Paths'?

Comment: If I erase that code that you sent me. I get 500 errors saying that the libxml is not there. But no error on the cocoa :no file or directory.

Comment: Very very weird...... can you check the project you copied from to see where it is importing its headers from?

Comment: oh yes, it's importing them as this: /usr/include/libxml2

Comment: Weird.... I would suggest adding the Cocoa framework back into your project and try again.

Comment: OK, I just erased everything I just did, and I'm STILL getting this error. So it's something else. Hmm...

Comment: GOT IT! I tried everything again, with your code. WORKS. weird :D I guess user error.